# UIImage to CIImage to UIImage results in pngData returning nil on iOS 12

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, core-image

I have an UIImage that I snap from the camera.
I want to do some image manipulations so I transform it to a CIImage.
`CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:snappedImage.CGImage];`
Next I do my thing, and then transform it back to a UIImage:
`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];`
If now I want to transform this to data to save it into Core Data for example:
`NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`
the data ends up being nil on iOS 12. (works on iOS 13, same thing happens with if I try to use the UIImageJPEGRepresentation)

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of problems emerging when using the `[UIImage imageWithCIImage:]` API. You see, your `CIImage` is not actually *rendered* when you call this method. The resulting `UIImage` is still just a "recipe" for how to create the result. It's up to the user of the `UIImage` to know that and trigger the rendering if needed. `UIImageView`s seem to know that, but I saw a lot of inconsistencies across other APIs.

What you can do instead is to use a `CIContext` and perform the rendering yourself explicitly:

```
// ideally you create this context once and re-use it because it's an expensive object
CIContext* context = [CIContext context];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);

NSData* data = [context PNGRepresentationOfImage:ciImage format:kCIFormatBGRA8 colorSpace:colorSpace options:nil];

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

This should work consistently in any iOS version.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The `pngData` docs states: "May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format". So the `imageWithCIImage:` creates a valid image, but the image has no `CGImageRef` associated, so it won't work with the `UIImagePNGRepresentation`?

Comment: Basically, yes. A `UIImage` is only just a wrapper around either a `CGImageRef` (bitmap data in RAM), an image source (e.g., something that's pointing to a file on disc), or a `CIImage`, which in turn is a "recipe" for creating an image (on the GPU). Only when you use the `UIImage` somewhere, the actual bitmap data is created/read.